# Relative Layout didn't Work in Android Studio Always Shows Constraint Layout in Design View

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

After the android studio update, The relative layout didn't work android studio always shows constraint layout in design view.

Even I selected the relative layout but it always asked for constraining the widgets.

I already tried to search online on different forums but no solution I found.

In this, I used 2 edit texts as shown in the image I want relative layout because it's more convenient but now it's not working.

Can someone please help to find where I am doing mistake?

Here is the design view
[design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGvc5.png)

Here is the XML of the code

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="enter email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_email"
            android:hint="enter password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_password"
            android:text="Submit" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlpik.png
```

Comment: I would advice you to include some code into your question, such as the XML layout, into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints has the same functionality as the below or start_of that the relative_layout had... but

i suggest that you replace your

> android:layout_below

to this or or if you don't needed also can be constrained into the parent like:

> app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" or "@id/your_component_id

but remember that this can work only if all the childrens are wrapped inside a constraint_layout. and wrap your relative layout inside of a constraint_layout.